# is there a good listing of projects like apache software foundation?

Tags: apache, open-source

I was wondering if there is a high-quality, (with open source software) listing of projects like the apache software foundation.

How about one that groups projects into domains, i.e. web frameworks, messaging, etc?

( I was looking for something to help pick open-source technologies for a particular problem when developing projects from scratch )

Comment: when I say apache software foundation, I don't mean a web server, I mean all the projects listed on projects.apache.org:

http://projects.apache.org/indexes/category.html

i mean this page is almost exactly what I was looking for. ohloh is the closest since it has varieties of projects

Comment: Thank you all for a very quick response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might look into [Ohloh](http://www.ohloh.net/). It lists quite a large number of project from across different project management sites. It categorizes them using tags.

It also provides stats on how active the projects are, which is often nice to see whether or not a project is still active.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Free Software Directory](http://directory.fsf.org/).  There's a Categories sidebar if you scroll down the page.

Answer (score 1):

We use some of the [OpenSymphony](http://www.opensymphony.com/) components:

- SiteMesh
- Quartz

...just to pick two.

Answer (score 1):

open source project hosting:

- http://code.google.com/
- http://sourceforge.net/

projects such as apache:

- http://codehaus.org/
- http://www.opensymphony.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net) and [Freshmeat](http://freshmeat.net) both have searchable databases of open source software.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia to the rescue!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open_source_software_packages)